# How to change opacity of an individual image

Tags: html, css

I have written css as below to reduce the opacity of images on a webpage:

```
img {
    opacity: 1; 
    -webkit-transition: .5s;
       -moz-transition: .5s;
        -ms-transition: .5s;
         -o-transition: .5s;
            transition: .5s;
}

img:hover {
    opacity: 0.6;
}
```

My question is how do I reduce opacity on mouse hover for an individual image in the html and not all the images on the page?

I have tried `#image-id:hover {}` and `.image-class` already and these make the image disappear.

**Edit:**

These are the two images:

```
<center>
    <img src="Online video editor.png" alt="Online video editor" class= "upload-file-image" id= "upload-file-image"height="200" width="300" style="opacity: 1;">
</center>

<center>
    <img src="jason-strull-KQ0C6WtEGlo-unsplash.jpg" alt="Online video editor page background" class= "page-background-image">
</center>
```

I wish to keep `src="jason-strull-KQ0C6WtEGlo-unsplash.jpg"` opaque and change the opacity of `src="Online video editor.png"` on mouse hover.

Sorry if I am a bit confusing, this is my first post :)

Comment: Classes should be referenced using the `.` selector, not the `#` selector (which is actually used for IDs). Maybe you want: `.image-class:hover { }`?

Comment: If you show us the HTML code this is applied to, we might be able to help!

Comment: Switching to .'image-class':hover {} the image just disappears, the same with #'image-class':hover {}

Comment: Remove the quotation marks and just write .image-class:hover { }

Answer (score 0):

If you use `img` you selecet *all* the images, by adding a `.class` or an `#id` you can select certain elements to apply the effect on.

```css
.opacity {
    opacity: 1; 
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s;
       -moz-transition: opacity .5s;
        -ms-transition: opacity .5s;
         -o-transition: opacity .5s;
            transition: opacity .5s;
}

.opacity:hover {
    opacity: .6; 
}
```

```html
<center>
  <img src="https://www.talkwalker.com/images/2020/blog-headers/image-analysis.png" alt="Online video editor" class="upload-file-image, opacity" id="upload-file-image" height="200" width="300"></center>

<center>
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg" alt="Online video editor page background" class="page-background-image opacity">
</center>
```

Hope I could help you out :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, when I use .class or #id the image disappears completely. The source files for my images are local and not from a URL. I don't know if this makes a difference? Thanks :)

Comment: @JonathanWindsor. I adapted my HTML for you, just copy it and replace the `src`s I used with yours, remember there shouldn't be a space between `class=` and `"opacity"`, instead  go `class="opacity"`.

Comment: @JonathanWindsor. It shouldn't make any difference wether you use local or imported images.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your first `img` tag has an inline style of - `style="opacity: 1;"`

Remove that and you should be good to go, as you're already setting the opacity in the css!

Demo: https://codepen.io/j_watson89/pen/oNxWEBp